# datepicker customize calendar

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to change the appearance of jQuery's `datepicker` in the following way:
Instead of simply listing the days of the month, I'd like each day within the calendar to also contain some other information (e.g., an icon, or a word). This icon/word will provide the user with additional information regarding that day of the month (for example, "rainy").
I've looked all through SO - I haven't been able to find a way to do this so far.
Does anyone have any idea how/if this can be done?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI widgets can be extended using [Widget factory](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/). Here is a [nice intro from jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/).

You could overwrite `beforeShowDay` method and add a custom css class (e.g. `rain`) based on some condition. If that's not gonna work, you could go deeper and extend both `beforeShow` and `changeMonth` methods.